# Custom token replacement

Tags: 6, tokens

I am using [Notification](http://drupal.org/project/notifications) to subscribe to different content types so that I can receive emails when a user creates/updates a particular content type.

The following is an email I generally receive from Notification.

```
 Greetings, ajinkya.

    These are your messages
    New content of type Blog has been submitted
    - Blog Test, Friday April 12
    Read more [node-url]
```

The problem is that the token `[node-url]` is not being replaced with a link to the node that has been created, and I am not able to find any interface that would allow me modify the token replacement behavior. Do I need to manually change the code in Notification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [node-url] token is a real token define by the token module. I would make sure you have the latest version of the token module. I believe this token has changed names a couple of times but I think thats the correct token.

I would make sure you're running the latest version of the [token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module if not update and hopefully that would fix your problem.

Comment: thanks. I updated the module from 6.x-1.12 to 6.x-1.15 and it did fix the problem.